# How do I send the same message to all consumers of a kafka topic?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have one Kafka topic with one group and one partition

I have 15 Kafka consumers subscribed to the topic

I want to all of the consumers to receive a message when I publish it.

I am using pythonkafka library.

Is it possible in Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

Give all consumers a unique consumer group id, then they each have individually tracked offsets and receive the same messages

Comment: One topic. 10 groups. 10 consumers. 1 partition each topic. Is that right?

Comment: Right. Number of partitions doesn't matter, in this case, though